# clojure: given a list of maps, get the total sum value of a specific key value

Tags: clojure

Input: `[{:a "ID1" :b 2} {:a "ID2" :b 4}]`

I want to only add up all the keys `:b` and produce the following:

Result: `6`

I thought about doing a `filter?` to pull all the numbers into vector and add it all up but this seems like doing work twice. I can't use `merge-with +` here since the `:a` has a string in it. Do I use a `reduce` here with a function that will pull the appropriate key?

`(reduce (fn [x] (+ (x :b))) 0 list-of-maps)`

It would be even nicer if I could retain the map structure with updated value `({:a "ID1" :b 6})` but since I don't really need the other keys, just the total sum is fine.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each of the maps will contain `:b` mapped to some number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to only add up all the keys :b and produce the following:
>
> Result: 6

I believe workable code is:

```
(def m1 {:a 1, :b 2})
(def m2 {:a 11, :b 12})
(def m3 {:a 21, :b 22})
(def ms [m1 m2 m3])

(->> ms
     (map :b)
     (reduce +))
```

I feel use of `->>` here can help readability in your situation.

This says to take action on `ms`, which is defined to be a vector of maps, [threading](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) incremental results through the remaining forms.

The first thing is to transform each entry of maps using the keyword `:b` as a function on each, extracing the value corresponding to that key, resulting in the sequence:

```
(2 12 22)
```

You can then apply `reduce` exactly as you intuit across that seq to get the result:

```
user=> (def m1 {:a 1, :b 2})
#'user/m1
user=>     (def m2 {:a 11, :b 12})
#'user/m2
user=>     (def m3 {:a 21, :b 22})
#'user/m3
user=>     (def ms [m1 m2 m3])
#'user/ms
user=>     (->> ms
  #_=>          (map :b)
  #_=>          (reduce +))
36
```

---

I'm a tad confused by what you intend by this part of the question:

> It would be even nicer if I could retain the map structure with updated value ({:a "ID1" :b 6})

Do you want to have each value for `:b` across all maps contain the sum of them all in a result, or something else?

Comment: why doesn't this work `(reduce (fn [x] (+ (x :b))) 0 list-of-maps)`

Comment: @user299709 Because the function you pass to [`reduce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) must take two arguments.

Comment: @SamEstep ah because it is `key value`, in that case do I just use `[k v]`

Comment: It isn't because of the key value. It is because both the first argument to reduce (the 0) and the map entry are sent to the function. So something like this would work for you `(reduce (fn [sum x] (+ sum (:b x))) 0 list-of-maps)`

Sum will then have 0 first time it is passed and increments up until done and is returned when reduce finishes.

Answer (score 2):

```
(reduce + (map :b list-of-maps))
```

Answer (score 0):

This its simple but it works!
    user=> (+ (your-map :b) (your-map :b))

or

```
user=> (def x [{:a "ID1" :b 2} {:a "ID2" :b 4}])
#'user/x
user=> (+ ((first x) :b) ((second x) :b))
6
user=>

or user=> (+ ((nth x 0) :b) ((nth x 1) :b))
6
```